# How to make where query with join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in which i have four columns

1. id
2. user_type
3. user_role
4. org_id

Now if the `user_type` is 1 (i.e individual) then the `user_role` and `org_id` will be null,
but if the `user_type` is 2 (i.e organisation) then it will have `org_id` (id of the organisation) and `user_role` (his role in the organisation).

There are three type of role in an organisation

1. admin (only one person could be the admin).
2. finance secrearty (could be more than one).
3. approvers (also could be more than one).

What I want
I want to fetch only one person (probably admin of the organisation) if the `user_type` is 2 from each organisation and all the users having `user_type` 1.

My table

```
-------------------------------------
| tbl_user                           |  
-------------------------------------
| id | user_Type | user_role | org_id|
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | null      | null  |
| 2  | 2         | 1         | 1     |
| 3  | 2         | 2         | 1     |
| 4  | 2         | 3         | 1     |
| 5  | 2         | 3         | 1     |
| 6  | 1         | null      | null  |
| 7  | 2         | 1         | 2     |
| 8  | 2         | 2         | 2     |
| 9  | 2         | 3         | 2     |
| 10 | 2         | 3         | 2     |
```

by using query

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.user_type = 1 
   OR t.user_role = 1
```

Expected result

```
-------------------------------------
| tbl_user                           |  
-------------------------------------
| id | user_Type | user_role | org_id|
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | null      | null  |
| 2  | 2         | 1         | 1     |
| 7  | 2         | 1         | 2     |
| 6  | 1         | null      | null  |
```

Then i have to join the result with tbl_user_meta with (where zipcode = 85225).

My tbl_user_meta follows-

```
 -------------------------------------
| tbl_user_meta                       | 
--------------------------------------
| id | uid       | user_name | zipcode|
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | abc       | 85225  |
| 2  | 2         | asd       | 85225  |
| 3  | 3         | asd       | 85225  |
| 4  | 4         | sdf       | 345678 |
| 5  | 5         | fgd       | 23456  |
| 6  | 6         | rgy       | 23567  |
| 7  | 7         | hyt       | 12345  |
| 8  | 8         | ukl       | 12345  |
| 9  | 9         | tko       | 21334  |
| 10 | 10        | ert       | 85225  |
```

What i finally want to achieve is this record

```
-------------------------------------
| tbl_user_meta                       | 
--------------------------------------
| id | uid       | user_name | zipcode|
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | abc       | 85225  |
```

P.S - I am doing this with codeigniter

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your work? What do you want? pure sql or how to build query using ci models?

Comment: you want data where user_type is 1 and 2 right......or you want data from table where user_type is 1 or 2.. clear this confusion

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed   What I want I want to fetch only one person (probably admin of the organisation) if the user_type is 2 from each organisation and all the users having user_type 1.

Comment: use my query I think it is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have my answer:

```
 $this->db->select('tbl_user.*,tbl_user_meta.*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_user');
 $this->db->where('user_type', 1);
 $this->db->or_where('user_role', 1);
 $this->db->where('tbl_user_meta.zipcode',85225);
 $this->db->join('tbl_user_meta','tbl_user_meta.did=tbl_user.id');

 $query=$this->db->get();

 return $query->result();
```

Comment: try my query is that what you want?

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed    is there any thing wrong with this one because when i tested it in my application it gives me right data.

Comment: you mean your query gives right data and my query does not work??

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed no i did not mean that. I didn't tried your code because  before posting your answer i figured it out by my query

Answer (score 0):

you can join the table as under remember remove "" from "85225" if it is integer.

```
select * from tbl_user, tbl_user_meta where tbl_user.id = tbl_user_meta.id AND tbl_user_meta.zipcode = "85225";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.uid, b.username, a.zipcode
from tbl_user_meta a
inner join tbl_user b
where a.uid = b.id ;
```

This can be achieved like this in codeigniter.

```
public function gettable(){
$query ='select a.id, a.uid, b.username, a.zipcode
    from tbl_user_meta a
    inner join tbl_user b
    on a.uid = b.id 
    where a.zipcode = 85225';

   $query = $this->db->query($query);
   $result = $query->result();
   return $result; 
}
```